# SQL - Filter redundant duplicates

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a table "Conflicts" containing two process ID's (processIDA int, ProcessIDB int).

A unique conflict is defined when 2 processes in any order (A/B or B/A) are entered into this "Conflicts" table.

The conflicts table contains duplicates as follows:

[row..1] ProcessIDA=**5**, ProcessIDB=***6***

[row..2] ProcessIDB=***6***, ProcessIDA=**5**

What I need to do is to filter out the duplicate conflicts so that I am left with only:

[row..1] ProcessIDA=**5**, ProcessIDB=***6***

Note: This table's rows can vary between 5 and 50 million records. Once I can successfully filter out the duplicates, the amount of rows will be exactly half of the current.

Comment: So you want a delete query?

Comment: Just a where clause filter would be fine (if possible). I could then use that where clause to delete or perform other queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete the duplicates,then

**Query**

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
  case when ProcessIDA < ProcessIDB
  then ProcessIDA else ProcessIDB end as column1,
  case when ProcessIDA < ProcessIDB
  then ProcessIDB else ProcessIDA end as column2
  from conflicts
),
cte2 as
(
    select  rn = row_number() over
    (
        partition by cte.column1,cte.column2
        order by cte.column1
    ),*
    from cte
)
delete from cte2
where rn > 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e769a/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple self join

```
;WITH   Conflicts   AS
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM    (   VALUES
                (6, 5),
                (5, 6),
                (1, 2),
                (1, 3)
            )   Sample (ProcessIDA, ProcessIDB)
)
SELECT  A.*
FROM    Conflicts A
JOIN    Conflicts B
    ON  A.ProcessIDA = B.ProcessIDB AND
        A.ProcessIDB = B.ProcessIDA
```